# Django get_or_create and increment right after

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a problem.
I want to store searched expression and increment its count right after.
I use `get_or_create` method, but it throws an error everytime.

models.py

```
class TopSearch(models.Model):
     expression = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and I want to do **this**:

1. If searched expression exists, increment its count by 1.
2. Otherwise, create it and immidietly increment its count by 1.

Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Maybe some thing like this would do, after suggestion from @Melvyn

```
from django.db.models import F

obj, created = TopSearch.objects.get_or_create(expression=something, defaults={'count': 1})
if created:
    obj.count = F('count') + 1
    obj.save()
```

Comment: i was wonderting what is `created` in `obj, created = TopSearch.objects.get_or_create(expression=something)` how it works

Comment: If it's created count = 1. If it's not count = count + 1 and should be saved. You can optimize that, by adding `defaults={'count': 1}` to get_or_create(), then add `if created:` for the rest of the code (and update_field=['counts'] as an extra optimization if table grows columns).

Comment: I agree, adding defaults is a good optimisation and plus code becomes more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
obj, created = TopSearch.objects.get_or_create(expression=something)
obj.count += 1
obj.save()
```

Get or create return the object and a boolean : True if created, False if get.